# Python script doesn't work when i run it with "python3 absolute path" but work when i navigate on the folder then run

Tags: python, wordpress, ubuntu, path

i have to implement a python script in a wordpress project.

so first i tried to run it from command line and it work correctly when i open my bash from the folder and run it

[image: screenshot where it work]

but when i tried to run it by drag and drop, it return me the following error

[image: screenshot where it doesn't work]

for my project, i need to make it work when i use the command "python3 absolute/path"

can someone help me with it ?

i work on ubuntu if it may help

edit : here is what i tried

here the code previously here on the main.py :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import json
from photovoltaique.roiPhoto import *
from bornes_rentabilite.pertinence import *
from bornes_rentabilite.calcul_roi_v2 import *
import sys
import os

sys.path.append(os.getcwd()+"/bornes_utiles")
sys.path.append(os.getcwd()+"/bornes_rentabilite")
sys.path.append(os.getcwd()+"/photovoltaique")
```

and what i had add :

```
sys.path.insert(0, "/bornes_utiles")
sys.path.insert(0, "/bornes_rentabilite")
sys.path.insert(0, "/bornes_photovoltaique")
```

and the architecture of the projet :
[Architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfYbJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

you need to tell it where to look for your modules ... I would think this would work

```
PYTHONPATH=/home/xxxx/code  python3 /home/xxx/code/script.py
```

you could also at the top of your main.py do it there as well

```
# at top of main.py
import sys, os
sys.path.insert(0,os.path.dirname(__file__))

import other_modules
```

Comment: Thans for your answer @JoranBeasley, i'm very new to Python but i think the first way you talk wont work if i move my work on prod environement so i tried the second one.

i, have updated my post to add more informations because we arre limited characters in the comments, 

i think i dont do it very well

Comment: use `os.path.dirname(__file__)` instead of `os.getcwd`